# Mongodb inconsistent result when querying from mongodb shell and mongo compass

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I am querying the DB from both a script with Mongoose and MongoDB compass 1.21.2.
In the one and only document I have in that collection I get:

in compass the sessionData object is present:

[image: compass]

in mongoose, sessionData object is NOT present:

```
   WhatsappInstanceReportModel.findOne()
   .where("userMobile")
   .equals("<some number>")
   .exec(function (error, data) {
    console.log(data)
   });
```

[image: mongoose]

Can anyone tell me why?
thanks